# Toggle Modules on or off at a certain time with Rules

Tags: 7, rules

I'm looking for a way to toggle a Module on or off based on the time of day using Rules. Ideally, the logic behind it would be something like:

```
IF

The time is between 1700 and 0900 AND Module X is turned OFF

THEN

Turn Module X ON

ELSE IF

The time is between 0900 and 1700 AND Module X is turned ON

Turn Module X OFF

ELSE

Turn Module X OFF
```

I'd like this to run with each CRON run (15 minutes). Is this achievable using Rules and without going into PHP?

Comment: Which module(s)?

Comment: I don't see anything in the rules code for enabling/disabling modules, so I'd imagine you'll need to write this yourself. It's very simple though, see [`hook_rules_action_info()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/7)

Comment: You would have to write your own rules action like @Clive stated. Then build a rule that reacts when Cron is run. Then you will need your cron to run on a set schedule.

Comment: In fact don't even bother with rules - this is about 10 lines of code in a `hook_cron()`, rules is unnecessary overhead

Comment: A lighter weight way of doing this is using Drush and the system cron. Write a small shell script to run Drush and disable the modules and re-enable them. This would be better for performance since enabling and disabling modules can take a while to do, you could run into timeout problems doing them in Rules. Drush should not have time out issues unless someone has changed the default behavior of PHP CLI

Answer (score 0):

Since you run cron in every 15 minutes, you can use [module_disable](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_disable/7) or [module_enable](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_enable/7) in `hook_cron` of your module. Using

```
format_date(time(), 'custom', 'l j F Y');
```

you can get the current date and time. What is difficult for you to build such module?